# os.path.join() does not work properly if try to join same folder names. How to fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, os.path

The code is as follows.

```
import os

path_1 = "/folder/data"
path_2 = "/folder/media"

print(os.path.join(path_1, path_2))
```

The output is as follows.

```
/folder/media
```

How to get the output properly like this.

```
/folder/data/folder/media
```

I want the solution for programs that depend on different operating systems. Therefore adding variables (path_1 + '/' + path_2) is not suitable for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

> If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component.

So, what you should do is remove the first slash in the second path:

```py
import os

path_1 = "/folder/data"
path_2 = "folder/media"    # <- removed first slash

print(os.path.join(path_1, path_2))    # <- prints /folder/data/folder/media
```

Comment: @trueThari cool! Please, make sure you mark it as an accepted answer so it's visible that it got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answer said, you just need to change `path_2` to be `path_2 = folder/media`, and it will work. You can also use the Pathlib library to ensure things are handled properly across operating systems:

```py
from pathlib import Path

path_1 = Path('/folder/data')
path_2 = Path('folder/data')

# extend the path to include path_2
path_2 = path_1 / path_2

print(path_2)
```